# Can't Add ReactNativeNavigation.xcodeproj to Libraries in Xcode

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation, xcode9.4

I can't add the ReactNativeNavigation.xcodeproj file to my projects Libraries. Any ideas on how to get around this? I left click on Libraries then click add files to my project then go into **node_module → react-native-navigation → iOS** but then I can't click on the `Xcode.proj` is like a disabled button when I click on it.

I'm using Xcode 9.4.1.

Screenshot:
[image: screen shot]

---

**Solution:**

Some how (probably my doing) the ReactNativeNavigation was added to the main project folder so I dragged it down to where the Libraries folder was, and the problem was solved. I suggest if you have this issue to search all the folder in your project, because it is probably already added somewhere in the project.

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Yeah i added my solution to the bottom of my question

Comment: @James can you post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted please?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered ReactNativeNavigation was added to the main project folder so I dragged it down to where the Libraries folder was, and the problem was solved. I suggest if you have this issue to search all the folder in your project, because it is probably already added somewhere in the project.